# Sun CodeModel: Annotation within annotation

Tags: java, annotations, code-generation

How can a create an annotation like

```
@Table(name="batch", uniqueConstraints=
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"compound_id", "batch_Number"}))
```

using suns codemodel package?

My problem is the `@UniqueConstraint` Annotation withn `@Table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is embarrassing. You just need to use `.annotationParam` instead of `.param`.

```
JAnnotationUse uniqueConstraint = tableAnnotation.annotationParam("uniqueConstraints", UniqueConstraint.class);
JAnnotationArrayMember uniqueFields = uniqueConstraint.paramArray("columnNames");
for (String fieldName : uniqueConstraints) {
    uniqueFields.param(fieldName.trim());
}
```

don't now how i could oversee this method...